# How to access the values in nested dictionary sent to django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm sending a nested custom dictionary through my views, that nested dictionary is 'history'

```
def update_participation(request,user_id,event_id):
    ev=Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    data=Participated(user=user_id,event=event_id)
    data.save()
    participated=Participated.objects.filter(user=user_id)
    i=0

    #Declared the dictionary history
    history={}

    #Adding values to dictionary
    for partcipate in participated:
        name=Event.objects.get(id=partcipate.event)
        name1=name.name
        fest=Fest.objects.get(id=name.fest_id.id)
        fest1=fest.name
        clg=College.objects.get(id=fest.clg_id.id).name
        history[i]={'event':name1,'fest':fest1,'college':clg}
        i+=1
    messages.success(request,f'You have registered for {ev.name}')

    #sending the dictionary to template
    return render(request,'webpage/my_events.html',history)
```

Example of dictionary will look

```
history={0={'event':'css battle','fest':'verve','college':'jss'},
         1={'event':'code wars','fest':'verve','college':'jss'},
         2={'event':'hangman','fest':'phase shift','college':'bms'}}
```

I'm trying to access the values css battle, verve, jss like

```
{%extends 'webpage/base.html'%}
{%block content%}
<h2 style="margin:5px 30px;"><u>My Event History</u></h2>
<div style="margin:50px 0px 0px 270px" class='table'>
    <table border='5'>
        <tr>
            <th>Event</th>
            <th>Fest</th>
            <th>College</th>
        </tr>
        {%for key,value in history.items%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{value.event}}</td>
                <td>{{value.fest}}</td>
                <td>{{value.college}}</td>
            </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </table>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

How am I supposed to iterate through the dictionary?

Comment: Why don't you make a list of dict items instead of creating a dict with a number and a dict inside it?

Comment: Yes, instead of having a dictionary, you should have a list of dictionary. something like this.... `history=[{'event':'css battle','fest':'verve','college':'jss'},
         {'event':'code wars','fest':'verve','college':'jss'},
         {'event':'hangman','fest':'phase shift','college':'bms'}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from some query optimization you can do, you should change your data structure. That makes it easier to access as well. See below:

method.py

```py
   def update_participation(request, user_id, event_id):
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        data = Participated(user=user_id, event=event_id)
        data.save()

        participated = Participated.objects.filter(user=user_id)

        history = []
        for partcipate in participated:
            name=Event.objects.get(id=partcipate.event)
            name1=name.name

            fest=Fest.objects.get(id=name.fest_id.id)
            fest1=fest.name

            clg=College.objects.get(id=fest.clg_id.id).name
            history.append({'event':name1,'fest':fest1,'college':clg})

        messages.success(request,f'You have registered for {ev.name}')
        #sending the dictionary to template
        return render(request, 'webpage/my_events.html', context={'history': history})
```

template.html:

```html
{% for item in history %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.event}}</td>
        <td>{{item.fest}}</td>
        <td>{{item.college}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, please give your variables proper names instead of name1 and fest1.

Comment: can I use the above list history[] in other views by declaring history[] globally?

Comment: No, you can't. If you need the exact same data in another view as well, I would create a separate method that builds the history data and call it from both views. @Gagankaranth